# Text tokenizer example

Tags: parsing, scala

Here is a partial example of a text tokenizer. I'm looking for ways to improve one particular line in this code:

```
  implicit class textFile(val fileName: String)  {

    def toDict() = {
      io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\\\r?\\\\n")).toList
    }
  }

  def filterComments(m: List[String]) : List[String] = m match {
    case Nil => List()
    case x :: xs => x.takeWhile(c => c != '#').trim :: filterComments(xs)
  }

  def filterEmptyLines(m: List[String]) : List[String] = m match {

    case Nil => List()
    case x :: xs => if(x.isEmpty) filterEmptyLines(xs) else x :: filterEmptyLines(xs)
  }

  def splitParameters(m: List[String]) : List[String] = m match {

    case Nil => List()
    case x :: xs => x.split("\\s*(=>|,|\\s)\\s*").map(_.trim).toList ++ splitParameters(xs)

  }

  val dict = "test.txt".toDict()
  println(splitParameters(filterEmptyLines(filterComments(dict))))
```

The line I would like to break up is the last one:

```
println(splitParameters(filterEmptyLines(filterComments(dict))))
```

Is there any idiomatic (Scala) way to make this more readable but keeping it compact, on the same line preferable?

Comment: It seems fine to me, tbh.

Comment: What is the purpose of `_.split("\\\\r?\\\\n")` in toDict?  getLines already removes newline characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've found a solution you like for the final line of your code, but I'm a bit concerned with the overall performance and characteristics.of your code.

Oh, I do have an alternative to your compactness solution but I will keep that for a different, shorter answer.

### Confusion of metaphors

`filterEmptyLines` filters the lines from `dict`.  `filterComments` *does not*.  It transforms them from possibly-commented lines into lines with no comments.  This may seem like a minor or pedantic point, but calling two different things by the same name can cause errors.  `stripComments` would be a better name, I think.

### Overengineered and unsafe functions

None of your three functions are stack safe. Each one of them is recursive but *none* of them is [tail-recursive](http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/09/27/tail-recursion-basics-in-scala/).  This means that processing a large file could blow the stack.

Each one of them can be rewritten safely using combinator functions, which are usually more efficient than pattern matching and explicit recursion (and gives an extra bonus that I'll explain later).

#### filterComments

This is not tail recursive because it prepends the transformed `x` to the beginning of the list returned by `xs.filterComments`.  It *could* be rewritten with a tail-recursive inner helper function, but this function can be done much more simply as a `map`...

```
def filterComments(m: List[String]): List[String] =
  m map (_.takeWhile(c => c != '#').trim)
```

#### filterEmptyLines

Unsafe for the same reason as `filterComments`.  Can be written safely as

```
def filterEmptyLines(m: List[String]): List[String] =
  m filter (! _.isEmpty)
```

#### splitParameters

Same as the other two, but multiple recursive applications of `++` is even more expensive.  This can be rewritten safely as

```
def splitParameters(m: List[String]): List[String] =
  m flatMap (_.split("\\s*(=>|,|\\s)\\s*").map(_.trim))
```

Oh, what happened to `.toList`?  Why does that work without it?  The answer is that Scala's `flatMap` does an implicit conversion of the array to a list.  Google `canBuildFrom` if you want to learn something about Scala collection internals.

### Over-specific types

Once those three functions are rewritten to use combinators rather than pattern matching, they don't need to take or return `List[String]`.  They could take and return `Seq[String]`.  This gives you more freedom abut what you pass in (could be `List[String]`, could be some other `Seq`-based collection).  No performance penalty (the appropriate filter/map/flatmap of the actual type will be called) and much more flexibility.  OK, at the end you would have to convert the sequence back into a list (or whatever you want the final form to be), but this allows you delay that decision till it is important.  This is that extra bonus I mentioned before.

And I'm about to explain why using `Seq` - or possibly `Iterator` could give a *big* performance boost.

### Multiple traversals and intermediate collections

`getLines` returns an iterator (a lazy, one-pass collection which only processes each element on demand).  But you immediately convert it to a list, reading the whole (potentially large) file into memory.  Then each transformation in turn creates an entirely new collection.  So you actually create 4 collections in a row, traversing the entire contents of the file 3 times (possibly 4 if there are no empty or comment-only lines).  But I'm pretty sure you only care about the final one.

Even if you always want to process the entire file, that's expensive (the bigger the file, the worse it gets).  And what if you only want to process the first `n` lines or process the file in chunks, not wasting memory on processed and not-yet-processed chunks?

There's a pretty simple solution which will give you all those options (but which doesn't force you to overcomplicate things just because you *might* want those options later).

1. Be lazy (use views, iterators or streams)
2. Don't keep a reference to any of the intermediate transformations.

#### Being Lazy

Option 1: List View

If you're sure you always want to read the whole file into a list, turn that list into a view.  When you apply `map`, `filter' or`flatMap` to a view, it doesn't process the whole collection *yet*.  It returns the original collection wrapped in a delayed transformation and only applies the transformation when you ask for the elements and only to the elements you ask for.  If you just apply another transformation to the new view, again, no processing is done, you just get a new view.  So if you apply all three functions to the view and only *then* ask for the results as a list, the original collection will only be traversed once, applying all three transformations to one element before proceeding to the next.

If you only take the first 10 lines from the final view, it will only process lines until it has 10 non-empty, non-comment-only lines.  The rest of the collection inside the view will remain untouched till you ask for it.

And none of the functions needs to know that laziness is happening, if they take and return `Seq[String#`, because a view is a `Seq`.  Bonus.

The drawback, compared to iterators, is that the entire original collection stays in memory until there is no reference to it and it can safely be garbage-collected.

Option 2: Iterators

`getLines` returns an iterator.  Why not stick with it.  `map`, `filter` and `flatMap` work the same with with iterators as with views.  So if your three functions take and return `Iterator[String]`, it just works.

The bonus that 1) the whole file isn't even read until you ask for it *all* to be processed and 2) the original, pre-processed lines are definitely thrown away and garbage collected.

The danger is that you have to be very careful to only traverse each intermediate iterator once.  So don't keep any references around.

Option 3: Stream

You could convert the `getLines` iterator into a stream.  This has the lazy file-reading advantage of the iterator and doesn't have the touch-only-once limitation of iterators.  However, it's actually a touch trickier than with iterators to make sure you don't keep the whole file in memory.  Oh, and `Stream` is a `Seq`.

Whichever of the 3 options you choose, you can still have `filterEmptyLines` and friends take/return either `Seq[String]` or `Iterator[String]`, because all `Seq` descendants have a `toIterator` method and vice versa.  So you can write them not to care about laziness or how you actually implement it.

#### Don't keep references (till you really need one)

For different reasons, you lose some of the benefits of laziness if you keep references to any of the intermediate collections (including the output of `toDict`).  With iterators, it's dangerous.  So

```
"test.txt".toDict().filterComments.filterEmptyLines.splitParameters
```

is batter than

```
val dict = "test.txt".toDict()
dict.filterComments.filterEmptyLines.splitParameters
```

(assuming the implicit class added)

Comment: Thanks, I learned allot from your post, very informative and educational !

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the functions in an implicit class, effectively making it a part of `List()`, makes for a much cleaner way of chaining function calls. Remember, implicit classes must be visible from the point where they are used, so either define them in the current scope or do an explicit import.

From this

```
splitParameters(filterEmptyLines(filterComments(dict)))
```

To this

```
dict.filterComments.filterEmptyLines.splitParameters
```

---

```
  implicit class textFile(val fileName: String) {
    def toDict() = {
      io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\\\r?\\\\n")).toList
    }
  }

  implicit class n(val m: List[String]) {

    def filterComments : List[String] = m match {
      case Nil => List()
      case x :: xs => x.takeWhile(c => c != '#').trim :: xs.filterComments
    }

    def filterEmptyLines : List[String] = m match {
      case Nil => List()
      case x :: xs => if (x.isEmpty) xs.filterEmptyLines else x :: xs.filterEmptyLines
    }

    def splitParameters : List[String] = m match {
      case Nil => List()
      case x :: xs => x.split("\\s*(=>|,|\\s)\\s*").map(_.trim).toList ++ xs.splitParameters
    }
  }

  val dict = "test.txt".toDict()
  dict.filterComments.filterEmptyLines.splitParameters
```

Comment: Self-answers are fine, if you explain your reasoning like in any other review. `n` doesn't sound like a good name for a class, though.

Comment: That's a lot of work when you could just do `(filterComments andThen filterEmptyLines andThen SplitParameters)(dict)`.

Comment: Why do you think this is cleaner?  If those functions should be usable on any List[String], it's simpler for them just to be functions, available wherever the containing module is in scope.  If they really should only be used in the initial stage of cleaning the input from a file, why not throw implicits away entirely and just use a class which takes `filename: String` as constructor parameter and contains these methods?